# Google OAuth2 - How to skip select_account prompt but display consent prompt with login_hint

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I use authentication code flow to exchange token in backend Nodejs.

I generate Oauth2 url and request `email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install` scopes.

The first time consent prompt, I select drive.file scope. After redirect_uri is sent to backend,
I have `sub` and I generate Oauth2 url again with `login_hint=${sub}`.

I expect that, select_account prompt can not be displayed but it actually displays with a Google account which is `sub`.

How can I skip select_account prompt (select that account) and display consent screen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70230552/11548522
Yeah he save my night. Appreciate it.